# How to find a button in Gridview and perform click programmatically in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am currently learning ASP.NET and I've been wondering if is possible to find a button that is in a Gridview and perform a 'Click' on it when the user clicks on another button not in the Gridview.

Thanks,
Y_Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to do this client side or server side?

Client side, you could find the GridView button via jQuery:

```
$('#<% buttonId.ClientID %>').click();
```

Server side, could you set the GridView's OnClick event to whatever you'd rather have it point to?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a document.getElementByID in a javascript and call the .click() of this button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridView.Row.FindControls('controlId')`

[You can check it on MSDN here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/320466e8-f5fc-474c-b46c-d7169588e87e)